# Why is the await promise function not defined

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to do async NodeJS v8.10.0 and Express like so.

```
app.get('/settings', async function(req, res){
  try {
    const getTemperatureSettings = await getTemperatureSettings();
    //...more await statements to be added.
    res.render('settings', {
      temperature_settings: getTemperatureSettings,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error temperatureSettingRange', error);
  }
});


function getTemperatureSettings() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    couch.get(temperatureDb, "/_design/settings/_view/range?descending=true&limit=1").then(
      function (data, headers, status) {
        const temperatureSettingRange = data.data.rows[0].value;
        resolve(temperatureSettingRange);
      },
      function (err) { 
        console.log('Could not get temperature settings', err); 
      }
    );
  });
}
```

However, I'm getting the following the error.

```
Error temperatureSettingRange ReferenceError: getTemperatureSettings is not defined
```

Even though `getTemperatureSettings()` is in the global scope, it seems it is out of scope --at least according to my syntax highlighter, it's not being called.

What is wrong here?

Comment: you use the same name for your local variable `const getTemperatureSettings = await getTemperatureSettings();`, so it shadows the function that is in global scope. (worth to note that var declarations are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) so they will happen before the affectation every time)

Comment: Thanks @Kaddath you were right. I can't believe I didn't realise something so obvious.